# Best approach to store historical data?

Tags: node.js, database, cassandra

I am using cassandra as database with a table "jobhistory"  partitioned based on timestamp . 
I have 2 million rows in jobhistory table and it can be increasing over time.

My Implementation: I am purging rows in jobhistory table every 7 days ie setting row level **TTL value of 7 Days**

Can any one suggest me whether to store in jobhistory table and purge it every 7 days or save it log file using node.js and winston logger  and do log rotation , which is the best way to solve this scenario. **Please, kindly give the supporting reason as to why it is better .**

Any better solutions are also welcome. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

It will be good if you put [TTL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useExpireExample.html) while inserting data in cassandra

ie

INSERT INTO kespace.tablename (c1, c2, c3, time) VALUES (2,'Hello','Mary',toTimestamp(now())) **USING TTL** 30;